# Symfony executing a java program that access DB

Tags: java, sql, symfony, concurrency, doctrine

I'm using Symfony & Doctrine to manage my entities.
One of my route launch a java program that need to use the same database.

The access are thread safe, i mean Symf/Doctrine Read/Write Table A and Read Table B
And Java/JDBC just Read Table A and Write Table B

Even if Doctrine write on Table A while java program is processing, the java program should still work without unwanted behaviour ( in theory ^^ ).

For now, when the java is launched from symf i've got the error : SQLState:S1000 ( Another connection have the lock on the tables ).

So how can I fix this ( R/W specifications or ??? ) ?

Or the only way is to give the needed datas for java program by another way ( files or ??? ) and say goodbye to performance ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was not coming from the Database concurrency access but it was due to my java Code with JDBC. SOLVED